# Azure documentdb create/query document dependency error in Application Insights

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-cosmosdb, azure-application-insights

I'm currently seeing many Dependency errors in Azure application insights, and I'm having trouble determining the root cause.

I currently have an API deployed as an app service within azure. The API is connected to a CosmosDB account for basic CRUD operations. While monitoring the default application insights, I've run across several Dependency Errors:
Type: Azure DcumentDB
Name: Create/Querydocument
Call status: false
res: undefined

This behavior seems to be very intermittent (maybe a problem with concurrency), but does not seem to actually be causing API errors as the query itself still appears to be completed successfully. Any thoughts on the root cause of the issue, or how to get details regarding the error specifically would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a screenshot of the end-to-end transaction for reference:
[Dependency Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDXeF.png)

Answer (score 0):

Is your app running on Windows? Is it compiled as X64/Release?

The "failure" is related to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/sql/performance-tips-query-sdk?tabs=v3&pivots=programming-language-csharp#use-local-query-plan-generation

Your app seems to be performing cross-partition queries, when the SDK is either not running on Windows or not built as x64 or when not all the DLLs that come with the nuget package are copied, it needs to do an HTTP request to obtain the Query Plan.

What you are seeing is the SDK retrying the Query Plan request because for some reason, you are having high latency (500ms is quite high for an HTTP request).